# How to add custom columns to a table that LINQ to SQL can translate to SQL

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, extension-methods

I have a table that contains procedure codes among other data (let's call it "MyData"). I have another table that contains valid procedure codes, their descriptions, and the dates on which those codes are valid. Every time I want to report on MyData and include the procedure description, I have to do a lookup similar to this:

```
From m in dc.MyDatas _
Join p in dc.Procedures On m.proc_code Equals p.proc_code _
Where p.start_date <= m.event_date _
And If(p.end_date.HasValue, p.end_date.Value, Now) >= m.event_date _
Select m.proc_code, p.proc_desc
```

Since there are many places where I want to show the procedure description, this gets messy. I'd like to have the lookup defined in one place, so I tried putting this in an extension of MyData:

```
Partial Public Class MyData
    Public ReadOnly Property ProcedureDescription() As String
        Get
            Dim dc As New MyDataContext

            Return _
                (From p in dc.Procedures _
                 Where p.proc_code = Me.proc_code _
                 And p.start_date <= Me.event_date _
                 And If(p.end_date.HasValue, p.end_date.Value, Now) >= Me.event_date _
                 Select p.proc_desc).SingleOrDefault
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Which works when displaying data, but you can't use it in a query, because it doesn't know how to turn it into a SQL statement:

```
Dim test = _
    From x In dc.MyDatas _
    Select x.proc_code _
    Where x.ProcedureDescription.Contains("test")
```

**Error**: The member 'MyProject.MyData.ProcedureDescription' has no supported translation to SQL.

Is there a way to turn a complex lookup (i.e. a non-trivial join) like this into something SQL can recognize so that I can define it in one place and just reference the description as if it were a field in MyData? So far the only thing I can think of is to create a SQL view on MyData that does the linking and bring that into my data context, but I'd like to try to avoid that. Any ideas would be welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert an AsEnumerable() into your query expression. That will convert everything to that point to a result set so that your custom properties can be included in the remainder of the expression (sorry I don't do VB):

```
var test = _
    (from x in dc.MyDatas 
    (select x.proc_code).AsEnumerable().
    Where(x => x.ProcedureDescription.Contains("test"));
```

Comment: I've done something similar in similar situations, but the problem here is that "MyData" could be huge, and the narrowing part of the query would come after the conversion to a result set. Still a valid answer in a majority of situations though.

Answer (score 0):

this is not an extension method, it's a property

VB.net Extension methods:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx

Consider using this query as a stored procedure if it's really important.